# Why does the MVC DropDownList helper behave inconsistently when using multiple DropDownLists after submitting the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I am by no means new to MVC but I consistently run into the same issue when dealing with DropDownList and DropDownListFor helpers where the helpers are not consistently behaving the way they should.

My current project is doing some pretty straight forward tasks and I am capturing input data from a user regarding payments and frequency. In my controller I am building predefined lists of List and passing them to my view.

```
    private List<SelectListItem> PaymentTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem {Selected = true, Text = string.Empty, Value = string.Empty},
                new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Cash", Value = "Cash"},
                new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Personal Cheque", Value = "Personal Cheque"},
                new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Business Cheque", Value = "Business Cheque"},
                new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Credit Card", Value = "Credit Card"},
                new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Direct Debit", Value = "Direct Debit"},
                new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Other", Value = "Other"}
            };
        }
    }

    private List<SelectListItem> Frequency
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem {Selected = true, Text = string.Empty, Value = string.Empty},
                new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Monthly", Value = "Monthly"},
                new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Quarterly", Value = "Quarterly"},
                new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Semi-Annually", Value = "Semi-Annually"},
                new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "Annually", Value = "Annually"}
            };
        }
    }
```

In my view I'm not doing anything different than you would normally do to create and populate a dropdownlist via helper. I'm simply taking the values from the ViewBag and then using DropDownList and creating the lists.

```
var frequency = ViewBag.Frequency as List<SelectListItem>;
var paymentTypes = ViewBag.PaymentTypes as List<SelectListItem>;

<li><label class="mediumLabel">Payment Type </label> @Html.DropDownList("paymentType", paymentTypes, new { @class = "input medium_textbox" })</li>
<li><label class="mediumLabel">Frequency </label> @Html.DropDownList("frequency", frequency, new { @class = "input medium_textbox" })</li>
```

Everything up until this point is perfect and when the view is loaded everything works correctly. The dropdownlists get populated and the user can select what they require.

When the user then submits the form if there are any missing fields and the model is not valid, the DropDownList and DropDownListFor helpers become inconsistent. With these two fields if both are selected and the view is returned to the user only one of the two drop downs will have a value.

What is actually going on here and why is it happening?

*added action*

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Output(AbstractOutput model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.Frequency = Frequency;
        ViewBag.PaymentTypes = PaymentTypes;

        return View(model);
    }

    //--
    //-- 
    var context = new Context();
        var options = new OptionsRepository(context);

        //-- add the request to the system
        try
        {
            context.Output.Add(request);
            context.SaveChanges();

            //-- alert the user that thier download has been submited 
            SendConfirmationAlert(context, options, model);

            return RedirectToAction("Output", "Output");
        }
        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {
            Log4NetService.LogException(Log4NetLevel.Error, ex, true);

            TempData["error"] = new Error
            {
                Controller = "Output",
                Action = "Output",
                Severity = Severity.Low,
                Description = string.Format("App is unable to to send {0} request confirmation", model.OutputType.ToLower()),
                Exception = ex
            };

            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log4NetService.LogException(Log4NetLevel.Error, ex, true);

            TempData["error"] = new Error
            {
                Controller = "Output",
                Action = "Output",
                Severity = Severity.High,
                Description = string.Format("App is unable to process your {0} request", model.OutputType),
                Exception = ex
            };

            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you re initialize the drop down list in your `POST` action method before returning the view?

Comment: Yes. In almost every case the view and drop downs behave the way they should and their selected values remain however there's always the one that loses its selected value, and when sent to the browser has no selected value. I've gone as far as to even force the view to use the value from the model thats returned to the browser and yet the view still refuses to display any value.

Comment: Can you show us your action methods, especially your `POST` action method?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to a common problem people have when using DropDownList, particularly when they name their item the same name as their select list.  MVC gets confused internally during model binding when it finds types that are the same as your posted name.

I don't like relying on the model state to populate like this and prefer to use strongly typed data.  Note that I keep distinct names, separate from names of other types (You have a property named Frequency, so change the id to FrequencyId in your model)

I would instead do this:

```
var frequencyList = ViewBag.Frequency as List<SelectListItem>;
var paymentTypeList = ViewBag.PaymentTypes as List<SelectListItem>;

<li><label class="mediumLabel">Payment Type</label>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PaymentTypeId, paymentTypeList, 
       new { @class = "input medium_textbox" })</li>
<li><label class="mediumLabel">Frequency </label> 
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FrequencyId, frequencyList, 
       new { @class = "input medium_textbox" })</li>
```

By the way, I wouldn't use empty strings for the first item, but would instead use the default value option from the DropDownListFor parameter.  The reason here is that if you don't set the initial value, then you have two different conditions... unselected, and selected with blank data.

There is a different symptom of this that you might see as well.  When using a SelectList of the same name, you get a "no parameterless constructor" error.  This is because the model binder is trying to instantiate the selectlist from the posted value.  It gets confused because the names are the same.